# Android Studio does not detect the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am a newbie in Android Studio and I can't test my programs. Before using this I succesfully tested my android programs in eclipse.

After reading some questions in similar context  I created a new emulator from

```
Tools-android-AVD Manager
```

But when I run the program it says No USB devices or running emulators detected(in select deployment target). How can I fix this

Answer (score 9):

Try enabling **USB Debuuging** in the **Android emulator** itself, like you would do it on a real device. **Settings-> Developer options->** enable **USB Debugging.**

Comment: It's work fine for me with a Pixel 2 API S on developer mode like on a real device : https://9to5google.com/2018/01/15/how-to-enable-developer-options-google-pixel-2-android-basics/

Comment: It didnt work for me.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of trying wipe data option, I tried Cold Boot Now option.
It worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try this in android studio menu

`Tools`
-->
`Android`
-->
`Enable ADB Integration`

if is is already `Enabled` try to `disbale` and `reenable` this works most of time for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **File -> Project structure -> Project -> select SDK version**. Then you can see emulator name in android studio

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the emulator before opening Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

**On Mac OS**, I ran into this when `JAVA_HOME` was set incorrectly on a new machine I had just set up.

Resolved by:

1. Running `java --version` showed a pop-up that the JDK was not installed.  I clicked the **More Info** button which took me to a download site.
2. Downloaded, and extracted to `~/tools/jdk-15.0.1.jdk`
3. In `.bash_profile` set `JAVA_HOME` with full explicit path.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for [Yogesh Kuma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63071931/4380127)

Sometimes wipe data helped.

if emulator launched you must close emulator,

open device manager -> open menu needed emulator -> wipe data->
you can launch emulator

Answer (score 0):

You need to try to find a very small fragment (small Emu rectangle right in the center of the screen) (minimized emulator window) and enlarge it in all directions :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Save your project to git
2. Wipe it from your computer
3. clone it
4. Open it with android studio

This steps work for me

Comment: Not a good approach.

Answer (score -3):

Go to **tools->android->AVD manager->then you can see the Android virtual devices**.

If you dont have any devices,at the bottom shows **create virtual device button** then create new Virtual device,If you face issue i'll help you !

Comment: I have already done this as I stated in the question. The problem is that after I finish creating a new emulator, it does not show me that emulator when I try to run my app

Comment: i think your SDK file may be  have problem