# Android Studio not detecting already running Virtual Device / Emulator

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

I am building my first Flutter application, and have set up everything needed for it such as Android Studio, the Emulator, and the plugins, etc. Now, the emulator launched successfully but the Android Studio isn't recognizing the running device, although I successfully ran the application on my physical device, but got no luck when trying to run on the emulator.

I have also enabled USB debugging and developer options but it didn't help me.

[Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL76T.png)

Can anybody please guide me on how can I fix this problem, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Open AVD Manager -> In the actions menu of your emulator device, select wipe data which would remove any misconfigured files from the emulator and reset it without having to create a new device and configure it again.

Note :- All the settings chosen while creating that Emulator device will stay intact but the apps installed in it the further modifications will be erased in the process