# (M1 Mac) Android Studio Doesn't Detect Android Emulator

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, apple-m1

I just downloaded android emulator through  android studio. Didn't use the GitHub repo to download dmg file. Then I started the S level API android emulator from and manager. Android emulator boots but android studio doesn't detect and doesn't run app on it.
What could be the problem?
Reproduced:

- Remove *.lock files in avd folder (Didn't work)

flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-arm, locale tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 2.2.1 at /Users/alperenbaskaya/Desktop/flutter
    • Framework revision 02c026b03c (2 weeks ago), 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
    • Engine revision 0fdb562ac8
    • Dart version 2.13.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/alperenbaskaya/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5, Build version 12E262
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 2):

1)Try enabling USB Debugging in the Android emulator itself, as you would do on a real device. Settings-> Developer options-> enable USB Debugging.

2)Probably the project you are running is not compatible (API version/Hardware requirements) with the emulator settings. Check-in your build.gradle file if the target SDK and minimum SDK version are lower or equal to the SDK version of your Emulator.

You should also uncheck Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration

If your case is different then restart your Android Studio and run the emulator again.

For more info:
[Android studio: emulator is running but not showing up in Run App "choose a running device"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198327/android-studio-emulator-is-running-but-not-showing-up-in-run-app-choose-a-runn)

[Android Studio does not detect the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672113/android-studio-does-not-detect-the-emulator)

Comment: I reproduced all the steps but didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I went to the AVD Manager and in the options for the particular emulator I selected "Cold Boot Now" and it resolved my issue.